# Why did Griphook stop working at Gringotts Bank?

Tags: harry-potter, character-motivation

In the [final Harry Potter movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1201607/) we see that Griphook the goblin isn't working at Gringott's Bank.

Is there an explanation why he doesn't he have a job there any more?

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Best if the goblins just explain it themselves, as they do in the book:

> There was another pause in which the fire crackled and the river rushed on. Then Ted said, “And where do you two fit in? I, er, had the impression the goblins were for You-Know-Who, on the whole.”
>
> “You had a false impression,” said the higher-voiced of the goblins. “We take no sides. This is a wizards’ war.”
>
> “How come you’re in hiding, then?”
>
> “I deemed it prudent,” said the deeper-voiced goblin. “Having refused what I considered an impertinent request, I could see that my personal safety was in jeopardy.”
>
> “What did they ask you to do?” asked Ted.
>
> “Duties ill-befitting the dignity of my race,” replied the goblin, his voice rougher and less human as he said it. “I am not a house-elf.”
>
> “What about you, Griphook?”
>
> “Similar reasons,” said the higher-voiced goblin. “**Gringotts is no longer under the sole control of my race. I recognize no Wizarding master.**”
>   
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 15 - *The Goblin's Revenge*</sub>

It seems clear that the Voldemort controlled Ministry was interfering heavily with the running of Gringotts, including giving a number of orders to the goblins that conflicted with their racial pride and beliefs.

Comment: I wanted to find this, but I don't have my books with me right now, +1 for posting it :)

Answer (score 0):

He refused to accept being under the control of wizards after the Death Eaters took over the ministry. More found on the [Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Griphook).

Comment: Please don't site Wikia. Its not canon and has been wrong and contradictory in the past.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr It's a Wikia, if you have proof it's wrong, edit it.

Comment: @LegoStormtrooper I only post Wikia when I know it is correct, I would have quoted the book, but I didn't have it with me at the time of posting. The Wikia is a collection of information that was gathered from canon.

Comment: @Nzall Yes.. assuming you can be bothered learning the syntax (and I'll be honest: as a system and application programmer I could easily learn it but I have no desire to learn it) and also assuming you agree to the politics of said Wiki (which unfortunately they have). Then there is the issue of others changing it after you do because they think you were wrong. Which means you wasted your time. Bottom line is it's not canon for the reason you suggest exactly: can be edited by anyone.

Comment: @ZenLogic My issue with that - and despite this being years later it's a very valid point - is that because anyone can change it it means you might be referring them to something that once was correct but now isn't it might not be. And if you know it's correct why not note where it comes from and maybe with quotes/whatever instead?

Answer (score 0):

Griphook stopped working for Gringotts bank as the Ministry of Magic was controlled by one of Voldemort's followers (a Death Eater). The Ministry was controlling Gringotts bank and Griphook refused to work as he didn't want anything to do with Voldemort or his Death Eaters.

Comment: Can you possibly provide a quote that Griphook wanted nothing to do with Voldemort?

Comment: This does not seem to provide anything additional to the existing answer.